# How to make my python script run on my GPU

Tags: python, gpu

I created a script to find a number inside pi:

```
from math import pi
from mpmath import mp
from time import sleep as sleep


def loop(find):

    #Breaks the find string into a list

    findList = []


    print('Finding ' + str(find))

    num = 1000

    while True:

        mp.dps = num

        string = str(mp.pi)

        result = string.find(str(find))

        if result == -1:

            print("Couldn't find " + str(find) + " within the first " + str(num) + " of Pi. Looking moving into the first " + str(num * 10) + " digits instead")

            num = num * 10

            continue

            pass

        else:

            print(str(find )+ ' was found at character: ' + str(result))
            break

        pass

    pass

def main():

    find = input("What do you want to find: ")


    find = int(find)
    character = loop(find)

    
    


if True:

    main()

    input = ()
```

When a long number is inputed it takes a long time to process for obvious reasons. I'm running an Intel i5-9300h and a GTX 1650. I am wondering if 1) I can make this code run on my GPU instead of my CPU 2) If so, how do I do this? 3) Would it even benefit performance?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) will help with what you're looking for. It can run python code [with CUDA support](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/overview.html) (i.e. your graphics card). Using CUDA for math is often faster than using a CPU because of better multithreading, however, whether you would get any benefit from it will depend on implementation. In your example I think you'll have to write a function that can approximate pi in a multithreaded way, in order to take advantage of what CUDA has to offer.